# sails populate sort not returning results

Tags: sails.js

Class model:

```
  attributes: {
    intervals: {
      collection: 'interval',
      via: 'classId'
    }
  }
```

Interval model:

```
  attributes: {

      classId: {
          model: 'class'
      },
  order: {
      type: 'int',
      required: true
  },
  }
```

controller

```
findClass: function (req, res) {
    Class
        .find()
        .populate('intervals', {sort: 'order ASC'})
        .exec(function (err, classes) {
            if (err) return res.serverError(err);

            return res.ok(classes);
        });
}
```

Data example:

```
   "intervals": [
        {
            "classId": 1,
            "interval": "78",
            "order": "2",
            "time": "30",
            "incline": null,
            "id": 1,
            "createdAt": "2017-08-23T22:10:57.000Z",
            "updatedAt": "2017-08-23T22:10:57.000Z"
        },
        {
            "classId": 1,
            "interval": "34",
            "order": "1",
            "time": "30",
            "incline": null,
            "id": 2,
            "createdAt": "2017-08-23T22:10:57.000Z",
            "updatedAt": "2017-08-23T22:10:57.000Z"
        }
```

Problem:
when I run this code with 1 class that has multiple intervals or without the sort, the intervals are properly. However, if I have multiple classes, an empty array is returned for the intervals.

I am trying to return all the classes with the intervals for each class sorted by order.

Comment: The sort passed to populate will sort the populated sub records - is that what you want? What does your data look like?

Comment: Yes that is what i want. I added an example of the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer my own question. I had a field named order, which must be a keyword in the underlying database and therefore cause issues. Changes the sort field to "intervalIndex" fixed this issue for me.